# How to set different frame to same view fo iPad landscape and portrait mode in storyboard?

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, storyboard, size-classes

For iPad, trait constraints are same for landscape and portrait mode. That is regular width and regular height for both?

How to set separate constraints for both mode, I need layout as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Landscape mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't handle that situation in interface builder only. I recommend you to use a `UIStackView` and change its axis on orientation change in code.

Maybe you also want to set up and activate / deactivate some width and height constraints for your red view to keep its correct size depending on the current orientation.

A solution could look like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var outerStackView: UIStackView!

@IBOutlet weak var redViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var redViewHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    let willTransitionToLandscape = (size.width > size.height)

    if willTransitionToLandscape {
        redViewHeightConstraint.isActive = false
        redViewWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    } else {
        redViewWidthConstraint.isActive = false
        redViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    }

    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        self.outerStackView.axis = willTransitionToLandscape ? .horizontal : .vertical
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```